# Select two of three in a triplet list {{x1,y1,z1}, {x2,y2,z2}}

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list of triplets `{{x1,y1,z1}, {x2,y2,z2}.....}` and would like to plot $x$ vs. $y$, then $x$ vs. $z$.  `ListLinePlot` will plot these if they were doublets, but how do I select pairs to plot?

Comment: Look at the documentation page for the `Part` function. You'll want to use something like `data[[All, {1,2}]]` for `{x,y}` and `data[[All, {1,3}]]` for `{x,z}`.

Comment: Thank you -- I did try Part, but I'm still learning the fundamentals of Mathematica (so far, I love it!).  I'll use your note as a template and come back with the results, when I give it another shot.  Much appreciated!  - Andy  OK, so I tried it right away -- Yes, it does work.  I was close, but it's not second nature yet.  Thank you!  I will return the favor to someone else.....

Answer (score 2):

Contrived data producing a list of 10 triples of the form `{{1, y1, z1}, {2, y2, z2}, ...}`.

```
SeedRandom[1]; data = Table[{i, Sequence @@ RandomReal[1., 2]}, {i, 10}];
```

Now we plot x & y and x & z.

```
ListLinePlot[{data[[All, ;; 2]], data[[All, ;; 3 ;; 2]]}]
```

or

```
ListLinePlot[{data[[All, {1, 2}]], data[[All, {1, 3}]]}]
```

Both display

[image: plot]

Note: Look up [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and [`Span`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) in the docs,